# Yakuake doesn't save shell setting

Tags: ubuntu, configuration

When I change the shell appearance opacity it works fine but when I reboot Ubuntu again, the opacity is back to `0` and I have to configure it again.

How can I save the Yakuake settings?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Unity. I have Cinnamon too but in both of them the settings don't save.

Comment: How are you doing to modify the settings? With "Edit current profile..."?

Comment: Yakuake ->settings->manage profile->edit profile->appearance -> edit -> background transparency

Comment: Ok, try with right click -> edit current profile.

Comment: There's a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149522) in saving/restoring sessions in yakuake, still not fixed. I think it may explain described issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure the profile is being correctly saved (I read somewhere there that Yakuake has a bug saving profiles)

The profiles are stored in

> $HOME/.local/share/konsole

Check that your DefaultProfile is properly set in yakuake by editing

> $HOME/.config/yakuakerc